# Why is a view controller created twice?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have the following code inside my `AppDelegate::didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    createContainer { container in
        let storyboard = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard

        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main") as? MainViewController else {
            fatalError("Cannot instantiate root view controller")
        }

        vc.context = container.viewContext
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    }

    return true
}
```

My MainViewController is created at startup, the stack shows the following:

```
0 MainViewController.viewDidLoad()
UIApplicationMain
main
start
```

And then is created inside the following line:

```
self.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

This is the first time I am seeing a vc created twice.
Is this normal ?
Is there I way I can prevent this ?

Comment: In your storyboard file, is your MainViewController flag 'is Initial View Controller' checked? Or is there an arrow pointing into MainViewController from the right?

Comment: Both. Is an initial view controller and has the arrow pointing to it

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure you do not need to instantiate it in AppDelegate::didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. By marking it as initial view controller, it gets added as the root view controller automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIApplicationMain` automatically instantiates the initial view controller of your main storyboard before you receive the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` message. You shouldn't be instantiating it “manually” in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.